# Orbit closure of two elliptic Möbius transformations

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-dynamics

Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be two elliptic Möbius transformations of infinite order in $\mathrm{Aut}(\bar{\mathbb{C}})$. If $\mathrm{Fix} (g_1) \cap \mathrm{Fix} (g_2) = \emptyset$, then can we deduce that $G = \mathrm{span} \{ g_1, g_2 \}$ is minimal? In other words, for any $z \in \bar{\mathbb{C}}$, the orbit closure of $z$ under the actions of $g_1$ and $g_2$ is $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$

Comment: Incidentally, what you call "span" is called the subgroup generated by the given elements, $\langle g_1, g_2\rangle$.

Comment: The correct statement is that the subgroup generated by two elliptic elements of infinite order is either elementary (has a global fixed point in the Riemann sphere) or is dense in a conjugate of $SO(3)$, or is dense in a conjugate of $PSL(2,R)$ or is dense in $PSL(2,C)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It seems to be an excellent classification. Do you have any reference for this result?

Comment: It is just the classification of closed connected subgroups of $PSL(2,C)$. The latter, I think, was discussed on MSE but is also easy to get by looking at Lie algebras. I will add a reference later on.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646183/list-of-connected-lie-subgroups-of-mathrmsl2-mathbbc). Let me know if you want to see more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot deduce that orbit closure is everything.  Here is an example.

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational multiples of $\pi$.

Let $R_\theta$ be the Möbius transformation that fixes $\pm i$, that sends the real line to itself, and which rotates through angle $\theta$.

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational multiples of $\pi$.  Let $g = R_\alpha$. Let $h$ be the conjugate of $R_\beta$ by the map $z \mapsto z/2$.  So $h$ fixes $\pm i/2$ and also sends the real line to itself.  Let $\Gamma$ be the group generated by $g$ and $h$.  Then the orbit of zero under $\Gamma$ lies in the real line, so is not dense in the complex plane.

---

More generally, we can conjugate $R_\beta$ by any Möbius transformation that preserves the real line.

Comment: Thanks for your good example. A Further questions is can we deduce that $G$ is topologically transitive? i.e., there is at least one point whose orbit closure is $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$

Comment: The answer is still "no", and my examples (above) are still counter-examples.  This is because the shared leaf is a "barrier".  I think that the orbit of any point off of the real line will fill half of the plane... but the orbit definitely will not be dense in the entire plane.

Comment: So it will not happen that $g_1$ and $g_2$ preserve another circle?

Comment: I think that is correct - they should not preserve another circle.